# A closed bounded set having exactly one accumulation point has the covering property

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I need to show that a closed, bounded set having exactly one accumulation point has the covering property.

A set has the covering property if any open cover of it has a finite subcover.

Since the set is bounded, isn't it simply contained in $(V, U)$ for some $V$, $U$. Thus it has the covering property? I'm definitely missing something... Not sure where the accumulation point comes in.

Comment: I don't know what you meant by (v, u) here, but your statement is false in arbitrary metric spaces. Also, your definition of covering property is generally referred to as compactness.

Comment: (v, u) being an open interval since if S is bounded then there exists u, v such that u > S for all s and v < S for all s, etc.

Comment: The covering property is about *any* open cover, not just the one you mentioned. Yes, that specific one you mentioned indeed has a finite subcover, since the cover is already finite to begin with. You also need to check all possible other open covers, including many that are infinite.

Comment: Ah okay, knew I was missing something. Still not exactly sure how the limit point plays into it.

Comment: It is a redundant assumption. Every closed bounded set of reals is compact.

Comment: I am not able to use that fact unfortunately. There must be some sort of property of having a finite accumulation set that allows me to make this claim.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the set (which you implicitly assumed lying in a Euclidean space)  $E$, and its sole accumulation point $a$. Since $E$ is closed, it contains $a$.

Suppose $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ is an open cover of $E$. We are to prove that it's possible to cover $E$ using only finitely many of the sets $U_\alpha$.

The point $a$, being in $E$, is covered by something. Formally: there exists $\alpha_0\in I$ such that $a\in U_{\alpha_0}$. It is reasonable to use $U_{\alpha_0}$ for our finite cover. It remains to cover the rest of $E$, namely the set  $E\setminus U_{\alpha_0}$.

But here's the key point: $E\setminus U_{\alpha_0}$ is **finite**, because it's bounded and has no accumulation points. So we enumerate its points $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and for each $i=1,\dots,n$ pick $U_{\alpha_i}$ that contains $x_i$.

End result: $\{U_{\alpha_0},U_{\alpha_1},\dots,U_{\alpha_n}\}$ is the required finite cover.

Comment: This is correct solution, but you should add the assumption that E is a subset of $R^n$ (assumed implicitly by OP).